# I/O Errors but no smart or ZFS errors

Tags: linux, debian, zfs, smart, dmesg

I'm having trouble to identify a problem for a friend of my. He is running ZFS on Linux with the Debian distribution. We are getting these entries into the dmesg.

`[273044.834151] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834157] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834161] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834164] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834168] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834171] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834175] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834178] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834182] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.834185] mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31110d00): originator(PL), code(0x11), sub_code(0x0d00)
[273044.841140] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[273044.841146] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[273044.841151] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[273044.841155] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, cause not reportable
[273044.841162] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 b4 0c c3 e0 00 01 00 00
[273044.841171] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 3020735456
[273044.841530] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] Device not ready
[273044.841532] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[273044.841535] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[273044.841538] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Logical unit not ready, cause not reportable
[273044.841543] sd 0:0:1:0: [sdb] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 b4 0c c1 e0 00 01 00 00
[273044.841550] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 3020734944
--- snip ---`

We have already did a complete scrub and that yielded no additional errors. We have also run a smart long test and that also passed the test. With no current pending sectors and also no reallocated sectors. What else can we try to debug this problem?

`SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   197   174   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       5150
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       5065
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       24
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       47
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   121   102   000    Old_age   Always       -       29
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0`

Running another scrub again.
Im using the ibm serveraid m1015 flashed to IT running on Supermicro X9SCM-F motherboard with wd20earx green disks.

  `pool: hulk
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub in progress since Sun May  4 14:26:11 2014
    33.2G scanned out of 10.2T at 254M/s, 11h38m to go
    0 repaired, 0.32% done
config:`

```
    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    hulk        ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        hulk1   ONLINE       0     0     0
        hulk2   ONLINE       0     0     0
        hulk3   ONLINE       0     0     0
        hulk4   ONLINE       0     0     0
        hulk5   ONLINE       0     0     0
        hulk6   ONLINE       0     0     0
```

errors: No known data errors

Comment: Please show the output of `zpool status -v`. Also, what type of server hardware, disks, chassis and SAS/RAID controller are in use?

Comment: Have you tried to run a SMART test. for example `smartctl -t extended /dev/sdb/` ? It looks like some particular sectors have problem, you can check them with: `hdparm –read-sector 3020735456` see if you get the I/o error. You can later try to write to the sector but this is DANGEROUS.

Comment: @ewwhite updated original post

Comment: @b13n1u I've have run the smartctl long test is it much different from the extended test?. I've hdparm read a few sectors but they where all empty

Comment: Long and extended is the same test. If there are no I/O errors on the disk sectors, then this could be a problem with the I/O controller not the disk. But you see the error only on one disk right?

Comment: @b13n1u yes only /dev/sdb errors thats hulk3

Answer (score 3):

log_info 0x31110d00 decodes to:

```
Value       0x31110D00
Type        0x30000000 SAS 
Origin      0x01000000 PL 
Code        0x00110000 PL_LOGINFO_CODE_RESET See Sub-Codes below (PL_LOGINFO_SUB_CODE)
Sub Code    0x00000D00 PL_LOGINFO_SUB_CODE_SATA_LINK_DOWN
```

Which boils down to the fact that the SATA device was reset, either on its own, by the SAS HBA or the OS.

You can use [mptevents](https://github.com/baruch/mptevents) to get the full info on the SAS HBA events (it seems to be an LSI SAS card, it won't work if it is a MegaRaid).

You can enable SCSI logging using `echo 0x010401cd > /proc/sys/dev/scsi/logging_level`

If none of the two show as errors than it will be internal drive asserts but these are very rare.

In addition I would suggest looking at the SAS phys to see if they indicate any errors in the invalid_dword files. You can find them in `/sys/class/sas_phy` directories.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Supermicro... :)

But really, wait it out. Get a spare disk, perhaps even configure it as a hot spare. This is what RAID protection is for. Your errors seem to be local to one drive/port/SATA connection. It rules out backplane (*there probably isn't one*) and controller as causes. If the drive goes bad, let it. Replace it as necessary.